# Determine whether $f_n(x) = \frac {nx}{1+(nx)^2}$ is cauchy in $[ C^0([−1, 1], \mathbb {R} ), d_\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have a homework question: Is the sequence
$$
f_n(x) = \frac {nx}{1+(nx)^2}
$$
Cauchy in the space $ C^0([−1, 1], \mathbb {R} ) $ with the metric induced from the sup norm? Could you please write down all of the relevant steps.

Also I do know what it means for a sequence to be Cauchy but I just haven't tried to do it with the sup norm before and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

My attempt:

So firstly I look at the sup norm relative to $f_n$, i.e.
$$
d_\infty=\sup_{x} |f_n|
$$
To do this I look at the maxima of $f_n$. i.e. when $\frac{d}{dx} (f_n) =0$
$$
0=\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{nx}{1+(nx)^2}\right) = \frac{n-n^3x^2}{(1+(nx)^2)^2}
$$
Thus at $ x=\frac{1}{n} $ is a local minimum $ \frac{-1}{2}$ and at  $ x=-\frac{1}{n} $ is a local maximum $ \frac{1}{2}$.

But I don't really know how to use this with the definition of a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: It seems to converge uniformly to 0. And hence it must be Cauchy?

Comment: @user119615 : If you are sure about this you can post it as an answer...

Comment: the solution states that it isn't cauchy here. see the link http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/SM/MATH3963/r/PDF/Week5-sols.pdf

Comment: i will edit my question so that includes my working thus far

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik any ideas on how to proceed now?

Comment: I do not know how does that help.... you have to find maximum of $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|$....

Answer (score 1):

$f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Since $f_n(1/n)=1/2$, the convergence is not uniform. It follows that $\{f_n\}$ is not a Cauchy sequence for the distance $d_\infty$.

You can also prove it directly like this:
$$
d_\infty(f_n,f_{2n})\ge\Bigl|\,f_n\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)-f_{2n}\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\Bigr|=\Bigr|\frac12-\frac25\Bigr|=\frac{1}{10}.
$$